# Why am I getting a MySQL Error 1062?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysql-error-1062

On one of my php pages, I keep getting the following error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

I don't know why or where this is happening, which is the reason I am posting this question.

I think it's happening in this code sequence somewhere.

```
// create user

$STH = $DBH -> prepare( "insert into users ( display_name, oauth_provider, oauth_uid ) values ( :value, :oauth_provider, :id )" );

$STH -> bindParam( ':value', $value, PDO::PARAM_STR, 255 );
$STH -> bindParam( ':id', $oauth_id, PDO::PARAM_STR, 255 );
$STH -> bindParam( ':oauth_provider', $oauth_provider, PDO::PARAM_STR, 255 );

$STH -> execute();

// get newly created user

$STH = $DBH -> prepare( "select * from users where oauth_uid = :id and ( display_name = :value or email = :value ) and oauth_provider = :oauth_provider" );

$STH -> bindParam( ':value', $value, PDO::PARAM_STR, 255 );
$STH -> bindParam( ':id', $oauth_id, PDO::PARAM_STR, 255 );
$STH -> bindParam( ':oauth_provider', $oauth_provider, PDO::PARAM_STR, 255 );

$STH -> execute();

$result = $STH -> fetch();

// create settings record with 0's

$STH = $DBH -> prepare( "insert into settings ( col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, user_id ) values ( 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, :id )" );

$STH -> bindParam( ':id', $result["id"], PDO::PARAM_INT, 4 );

$STH -> execute();
```

How do I find out which part is causing the problem?

Comment: set your primary key from scratch

Comment: @Negin, I don't understand.  I truncated the tables so I could start some testing.

Comment: your primary key is an integer isn't it?is it auto_increment?

Comment: I had this problem sometimes,i guess it is from mysql no relation to the code drop the column of primary key alter auto_increment to 1 again and add the key again

Comment: For the users table yes.  Seems like I forgot to set it to auto increment in the settings table.  Is that what the problem is?

Comment: Looks like that was the problem.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, this type of problem could have taken me days to find...  Please add it as an answer so I can accept it.  Thanks again.

Comment: you're welcome I just told my experience:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is from mysql no relation to the code

drop the column of primary key alter auto_increment to 1 again and

add the key again